# blend 4 code behind

Tags: expression-blend, blend

I am designing a template in belnd 4. I am new to .net and blend. I am trying to link a click event to the button but when I go tp properties and click the Events, I get this

```
The document item has no code-behind file. Add a code-behind file and a class before adding event handlers
```

I will appreciate help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to add an event handler for a button which is inside a ResourceDictionary file. A ResourceDictionary is just for storing control's styles. You can only do that in a UserControl or Page.

Comment: You are correct. However when I click to edit template, it automatically creates the ResourceDictionary file. How do I prevent it to do so , or how else can I do it in user control. Any article or a link to do that? I will appreciate your help. Thanks